# EXC_BREAKPOINT when using sortedArrayUsingComparator with a lot of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, nsarray

I'm trying to sort a set and it works fine most of the time. But when I start using my app on an old iPhone 5c and a lot of objects get into the set, I would eventually hit this error:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
```

here is the code plus stacktrace:

[image]

```
if(manager.allBeacons){
    NSSet *beacons = [manager.allBeacons copy];
    NSSet *filteredSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:[beacons filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    if(filteredSet){
        //NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"RSSI" ascending:NO];
        //NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
        //NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[filteredSet.allObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [filteredSet.allObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
            if([obj1 isKindOfClass:[BLUSBeacon class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[BLUSBeacon class]]){
                BLUSBeacon *beacon1 = obj1;
                BLUSBeacon *beacon2 = obj2;

                if(beacon1.RSSI.integerValue > beacon2.RSSI.integerValue){
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                }

                if(beacon1.RSSI.integerValue < beacon2.RSSI.integerValue){
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                }
            }
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }];
        if(sortedArray){
            self.beacons = sortedArray;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the last step in the stacktrace in case it serves any purpose:

[image]

As you can see, I was trying to sort with descriptors initially, but that made it crash even sooner.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not related but no need for the cast `(NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;`. A even quicker way instead of all your if/else: `return [beacon1.RSSI compare:beacon2.RSSI]` (or reverse `beacon1` and `beacon2`, I never know). Could you define `a lot of objects`? iPhone 5C is running on which iOS version? It's 32-bits, but I didn't see a place where it could cause issue.

Comment: iPhone 5C is running iOS 10.3.3. A lot of objects is around 40objects. Which I know it's not really a lot, but every time I see this problem it's over 30 objects. When it's lower it doesn't happen...